# Errors from a particular source when I update (in any of the package managers)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, repository, synaptic

When I update (using any of these, apt-get, synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center) I get several errors.  First is this warning:

```
Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/utopic/InRelease
Unable to find expected entry 'utilities-1.5/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, even where (else) to look for an answer -- what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: 14.10 reached end-of-life is no longer supported.

Comment: Since starting, with 14.04, I have spent dozens of hours trying to configure and secure a basically working system.  But I have as yet to get to work, and when I say 'basically working', it is still rife with error messages and such.  The upgrade was supposed to fix some of that, but instead introduced new problems and I'm not really sure where I stand -- please edit this and point out also how off target I am...I remember when forums were often a source of help, and before that Usenet groups / IRC: at least there was hope for content over format....

Comment: Some errors are to b expected. For example, this one is about the third-party MySQL repo, which you can disable until the upgrade is done (by commenting out the appropriate lines in ` .list` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.